# Scroll tableview row up when keyboard appears iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uikeyboard

My apps some ui components hides from bottom when keyboard appears, in fact its a `tableView's` last row.

I am using `NSNotificationCenter` to notify when keyboard appears and disappears.

Here is my code:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardOnScreen:) name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];
```

---

```
-(void)keyboardOnScreen:(NSNotification*)notification{
    NSDictionary* info = [notification userInfo];
    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
    CGRect screen = self.view.frame;        
    screen.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    float HeightOfToolbar =_inputbar.frame.size.height; //TOOLBAR
    float yPoint = screen.size.height-HeightOfToolbar;
    CGPoint scrollPt = CGPointMake(0, yPoint);
    [_dataTable setContentOffset:scrollPt animated:YES];
}
```

However, tableview scroll up but not at correct row i.e last row above keyboard.
Sometimes it scroll to second last row hiding last row, or more above.
its related to scrollPt value!

Comment: use `tpkeyboardavoidingscrollview` lib if you feel okay with it.

Comment: @vaibhav is it so difficult.. that i should use tpkeyboardavoidingscrollview??

Comment: i didn't mentioned anywhere word difficult in my previous comment.

Comment: If you use tableview controller with  cells the above one will default behaviour in that.

Comment: @Vinodh will try your suggestion :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this method keyboard appears

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
        NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];
        CGSize Size = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

        UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, Size.height - HeightOfToolbar, 0.0);//Set height according to key board height
        self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets;
        self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
        [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionBottom animated:YES];
        }
```

**Hide key board**

```
 - (void)keyboardWasHidden:(NSNotification *)aNotification
    {

    self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    }
```

Comment: every time i dismiss keyboard, after execution of  keyboardWasHidden ,keyboardWasShown is called!!

Comment: did you using any scroll delegate method?

Comment: yes.. scrollViewDidScroll and scrollViewDidScrollToTop

Comment: i have handled keyboardWasShown method calling after keyboardWasHidden. Can you tell me, why table row scroll up in table then scroll down to the last row!!

Comment: this method atScrollPosition: you can manage ScrollPosition top or bottom row

Comment: Table view scroll to few more index up  and then scroll down to last row. Example, if i have 10 rows, then table view scroll to 5 index and then scroll down to 10th row.